# guidance with rubymonk example

Tags: ruby

On [this page](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/5-strings/lessons/31-string-basics#solution2466) of rubymonk

There is a question posed as follows:

```
def string_length_interpolater(incoming_string)   
   "The string you just gave me has a length of " 
end
```

The solution to this question is:

```
def string_length_interpolater(incoming_string)
  "The string you just gave me has a length of #{incoming_string.length}"
end
```

and then it outputs this answer:
Output Window

stdout:

```
interpolates 2 when I pass 'Hi' ✔
interpolates 4 when I pass 'Good' ✔
```

I do not understand how this answer was given, as I dont see the word Hi or Good anywhere in the string.

Any help in understanding would be much appreciated, I am a complete newbie here so please go easy on me.

Answer (score 0):

The RubyMonk server is passing those values for your variable incoming_string.  A simple test to verify this would be to add `puts incoming_string` above or below

```
"The string you just gave me has a length of "
```

When you hit run, you'll see values for incoming_string as output.

Comment: I did not understand what you just wrote, it was a little over my head. Can you please explain to me why 2 and 4 for the words "hi" and "good" that don't seem to exist in any of the code?

Comment: RubyMonk has a script elsewhere that checks the script that you write to be sure it does the right thing. In this case, it is doing that by giving (or "passing in") the string_length_interpolater method two different strings: "Hi" and "Good". It then checks to be sure that the answer to the length of "Hi" is 2 and "Good" is 4.

Comment: Thanks tom that makes a bit more sense to me, but why is it so vague on rubymonk to understand that? The way it was outputting made it seem like the code was giving the wrong answer... Or that I am just that lost on understanding ruby